# how to pack jar along with config file as docker image

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile, docker-image

I have a `jar` file, `pom` file and `config.yml` file along with `dockerfile` inside a folder named **app** which is in **/Desktop**.
How can I pack all those files into a docker image?

This is my current docker file. What should I change?

FROM java:8
 
WORKDIR /
 
ADD /Desktop/app $HOME/app
 
CMD ["java", "-jar", "appserver.jar", "server", "config.yml"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start with this simple **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM java:8
WORKDIR /
ADD app /app
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/app/appserver.jar", "server", "/app/config.yml"]
```

The Dockerfile should be created in a directory which contains also the app directory with your *appserver.jar* and *config.yml* files:

```
├── workdir/
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   └── app/
|       ├── application.jar
|       └── config.yml
```

Now, to build the docker image, run, in the workdir, the following command:

```
docker build -t app-name:1.0 .
```

Comment: can you explain the change, please @thanh

Comment: just added in the answer

Comment: one more question @thanh, in  `COPY .  /app` that mentions root directory right?
that means it will copy all my files from the root into the image??

Comment: it means it will copy all files and folders in `/Desktop/app` to `/app` folder in the image.

Comment: CMD ["java", "-jar", "/app/appserver.jar", "server", `"/app/config.yml"`] only after making this change it worked.I have pom.xml file which is inside `app/` folder is not getting recognised.